# ImportError: cannot import name Profile django

Tags: python, django

I have created all my models in admin's model.py file, this admin app is my custom defined app, Now i want to use one of my model defined in admin's model.py file in my home's view.py file. so as per documentation i have write this code in home's model.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from admin.models import Profile
```

Profile is my model class that i have defined in admin's model.py file. but its giving error

```
ImportError: No module named models
```

and if i write this code in home's model.py file

```
from django.db import models
from models import Profile
```

it gives me error

```
ImportError: cannot import name Profile
```

Profile class in admin's model.py file is

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    subscription = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can i use this Profile model class defined in admin app in home's view.py file.
Please note that my admin app is custom defined app.

This is my Installed app settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin.apps.AdminConfig',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home'
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `admin.py` in the same directory? And show your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Comment: `admin` is a dangerous name to call your own app, as it will certainly conflict with the Django admin. Call it something else.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev please check edit

Comment: @DanielRoseman but at this situation, if i change my admin app to another name then i'll have to do a lot of work, please get me another solution if there would be any alternative of this.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev relative import did not work, giving error ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package